# How to hide table index along with table?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to hide a uitableview along with it's hidden. However, when I do

```
[self.tableView setHidden:YES];
```

However, the table index is not hidden.

Can anyone kindly point out what to do ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just make sure `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` returns nil when you need it to be hidden

Comment: the thing is, I hide the table when a button is pressed, how do I make sure that the said method also returns nil at the same time ? not sure  :-s

Comment: `if (self.tableView.hidden == YES) return nil;`

Comment: You might also need to force a `[self.tableview reloadData];` to trigger the update